# Comparison of self-hosted, distributed storage options for datomic?

Tags: cassandra, couchbase, riak, infinispan, datomic

From what I know about Datomic's [list of supported storage systems](http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html), it seems the following can both be **self-hosted** and are **distributed**.

- Cassandra
- Riak
- Couchbase
- Infinispan memory cluster

For someone who doesn't know most of these, what are the differences of them when it comes to being used for Datomic only. Datomic does not care too much about the respective features of the storage systems, as they are only used as a "dumb" key/value store.

So what is important to me are

- ease of setup
- ease of maintenance
- performance

Especially in terms of "ease of setup" there are probably significant differences, as according to the Datomic page, some of those require a ZooKeeper cluster, one need at least 3 nodes to function etc.

Answers are appreciated, even if they do not cover all storage options mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with August's recommendations.

I would also add that if self-hosting is not a hard requirement, setting up Datomic on AWS using DynamoDB is generally the quickest path.

-M

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for ease of setup, a plain SQL database is probably a good choice. Datomic can use most popular SQL databases as storage (using JDBC from the JVM), so MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc can be used. These are widely available, and typically easy to install and run on most setups.

Performance wise, I don't have much experience to share, just my thoughts. It seems to me that the main bottleneck would probably be Datomic itself, as it is writing transactions to storage in a single thread. I can't imagine that using a 5 server Riak cluster would be that much faster than a SQL server. In terms of reads, Datomic supports having memcached between storage and the peers, so the difference is minimal for reads as well as writes.

The self-hosted storage is intended for dev/test/staging setups. Internally, it uses the SQL interface and H2 directly in the transactor. H2 is considered stable, but I've had a H2 db become corrupted in test/staging when a server unexpectedly restarted, so I wouldn't recommend it for production.

Comment: I am asking for a *distributed* storage system specifically, for one because I want it to be resilient in the face of a machine going down. This can of course be done with most SQL database systems, but it's not that easy to set up and maintain. Another advantage is you can easily scale out distributed systems and thus increase read performance (for data that's not cached by the Datomic peer in question). In terms of "self-hosting", what I mean is not "in-process", but hosted in-house, in contrast to some cloud-based system like DynamoDB.